# Keycloak is not working with spring boot [invalid_user_info_response]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I am running a local Keycloak instance, that is supposed to be connected with my spring boot app.
When I log in, I get redirected to an error page.

I think my spring boot app is configured correctly.
The application.yaml looks like this:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          keycloak:
            client-id: login-app
            client-secret: <secret>
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:8082/realms/<realm>
            token-uri: http://localhost:8082/realms/<realm>/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

When I try to access an API resource from the browser I get the keycloak login view:
[image: Keycloak Login]

But after logging in it shows the following:
[image: Login Error]

In the administration console I see a logged in session, so I guess even the login itself worked:
[image: Logged in User Session]

I took some screenshots of my keycloak configuration:

Client config:
[image: Client Config 1]
[image: Client Config 2]

Realm role:
[image: Realm Role Config]

User config:
[image: User Config 1]
[image: User Config 2]

I think it is an issue with my keycloak configuration in the admin console.

Does anyone know this and has a solution/explanation for it? Is there anything I missed?
If further information is needed I am happy to provide!

Thanks in advance
Paul

Comment: Configuring a REST API as an OAuth2 client is not the way I'd recommand: requests will be secured with session, not access token. I'd recommand to configure it as resource server (requests secured with access tokens). More there: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials

Comment: Okay, I will have a look into this, thanks! :)

Comment: can you please tell what was the name of realm in this case? @PD

Answer (score 0):

Please give a try to:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          keycloak:
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            client-id: login-app
            client-secret: <secret>
            provider: keycloak
            scope: openid,profile,email,offline_access
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:8082/realms/<realm>

logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    org:
      springframework:
        security: TRACE
```

If this doesn't work, add the traces of a complete authorization code flow to your question.

Comment: That solved my problem, can you explain?
I have a working application with the configuration I used before..
I guess my problem had something to do with the "scope"?